# Javascript can't find element for collapsing header

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Javscript:

```
var navTop = document.getElementsByClassName('main-nav');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   if(window.pageYOffset > 100) {
     navTop.classList += ' .small';
   } else{
     navTop.classList = 'main-nav';
   };
});
```

The header:

```html
<div>
  <header class='main-nav'>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <a href='#aboutme'>
          <li>About Me</li>
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href='#projects'>
          <li>Projects</li>
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href='#experience'>
          <li>Experience</li>
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href='#contactme'>
          <li>Contact Me</li>
        </a>
        <br>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

I have the nav set to fixed, but the JavaScript isn't doing anything. Instead, it just shows a 'navTop is null' error every time I scroll down. Is there anything wrong with my syntax or logic that could be causing this? And if there is a better way to make a collapsing header, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: navTop.classList += ' .small'; remove . before word small

Answer (score 2):

As [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), you need to use elements using index and manipulate them. Here in example I have used `0` for first element.

Also as you are using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), its methods needs to be used to manipulate CSS classes

```
var navTop = document.getElementsByClassName('main-nav');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
        navTop[0].classList.add('small')
    } else {
        navTop[0].classList.remove('small')
    };
});
```

You can also use `toggle()` method as suggested by @David

```
classList.toggle('small', window.pageYOffset > 100);
```

Comment: Just because we can: `classList.toggle(‘small’, window.pageYOffset > 100);`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only one element with class `main-nav` you can use `querySelector()` to get the reference of that element instead of using `getElementsByClassName()` which will return you the array of elements.

Change your code to:

```
var navTop = document.querySelector('.main-nav');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
        navTop.classList.add('small')
    } else {
        navTop.classList.remove('small')
    };
});
```

Comment: It's still saying navTop is null